# How set Indentation to Google slide Shape Text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

We are trying to **Indent the Google Slide Shape**, by setting the **Left/Right indentation** values using Google Apps Script.

```
function indentShape(){
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
  var shape = slide.getShapes()[0];

  // shape.setIndent(Left,Right) 
  shape.setIndent(10,20)
}
```

Comment: What is your current code doing? Are you getting any error messages? Is it indenting your shape at all?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function setIndent in object Shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `setIndent()` is a method belonging to the XML script service but not Slides Script Service.
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/format
2. The Slides Script features the methods `setIndentStart(indent)`, `setIndentFirstLine(indent)` and `setIndentEnd(indent)` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/paragraph-style#getIndentStart().
3. Here an example how to use those methods:
   `shape.getText().getParagraphStyle().setIndentStart(20)`